# Example of a sequence that fit to these criteria

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $a_{n}$ is a converging increasing sequence (that is, that has a limit) and a limit is $\lim a_{n} = L$.  Let ($b_{n}$) be another sequence that “interleaves” the first one, that is, such that $a_{n} <b_{n} < a_{n+1}$ for all n. Prove, using a limit definition, that $\lim b_{n} = L$ as well. Give an example that shows that the conclusion ($\lim b_{n} = L$) cannot be more valuable if $b_{n}$ not monotonous.

Any help guys?

Comment: What do you mean by "the conclusion cannot be more valuable if $b_n$ not to monotonous"?  I think there may be a language barrier here.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I edited the question. Thannks.

Comment: $b_n$ is increasing and bounded, then $b_n \to M$. Why?

Comment: Suppose $M \neq L$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is $n_1 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a_n \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ and there is $n_2 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $b_n \in (M-\epsilon, M+\epsilon)$. Take $n_0 = \max\{n_1,n_2\}$ and choose $\epsilon$ such that $(M-\epsilon, M+\epsilon)\cap (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon) = \emptyset$. How to get a contradiction?

Comment: Also, I could not understand what means "$b_n$ not to monotonous".

Comment: By  "not to monotonous" do you mean "not monotonic"?  But $a_n < b_n < a_{n+1}$ implies that $b_n$ **is** monotonic increasing: $b_n < a_{n+1} < b_{n+1}$.  And what do you mean by "cannot be more valuable"?

Answer (score 0):

Since we have the inequality that $a_n<b_n<a_{n+1}$, by the shift rule, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1})=L$, so by the Sandwhich Theorem $(b_n)$ converges, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)=L$.

For an example: $a_n = (1-\frac{1}{2n})$, $b_n = (1-\frac{1}{2n+1})$

$(1-\frac{1}{2n})<(1-\frac{1}{2n+1})<(1-\frac{1}{2n+2})$,

$(a_n)\to 1$, and so $(b_n)\to 1$.